# Can driving in drive 2 damage my car

Tags: automatic-transmission, drivetrain, engine-load

Not going to over inform here, suffice it to say that my 1997 Jeep Wrangler engine begins to choke and cut off at stops.  Many ideas and repairs tried.  I recently found that driving in (Automatic) Drive 2 alleviates this problem.  Is it bad to drive around town between 25 to max 60 mph?  Am I damaging my engine or transmission? THX

Comment: Man, that thing has to be at pretty high RPM if you are running 60MPH in second gear. Maybe you could shift into drive when you are going fast and back down to 2 when you are around town?

Comment: I understand why you are asking this. Wonder if you have looked to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It won't necessarily damage either your engine or transmission. You should realize it will cause more engine/tranny wear due to higher than normal RPM usage. You'll also experience lower fuel mileage.

Comment: Also, a possibility of overheating if the cooling system is not in top shape.